# PHP Image Serving, extraneous bytes before marker

Tags: php, apache-flex, file-upload

I'm desperately trying to solve this one. I have a bunch of files stored outside of the webroot and I need to serve them to a user after a few auth checks. These files have been uploaded using a Flex application or have just been manually uploaded through FTP. I have a serving script that looks something like:

```
<?php

$filePath = '/for/demonstration/only.jpg';
...
$type = exif_imagetype($filePath);
$size = filesize($filePath);
if ($type && $size > 0) {
    switch($type)
    {
        case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
            header("Content-Type: image/png");
            break;
        case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
            header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
            break;
        default:
            header("Content-Type: text/plain");
            break;
    }
    header("Content-Length: {$size}");
    readfile($filePath);
    exit;
} else {
    echo 'error';
}
```

Pretty simple. <s>The image however, somewhere in the upload process,</s> Because of the encoding process, the file has gained an extra 100-130B, and now seems to be corrupted. I get the **extraneous bytes** error. The upload script is pretty simple as well, Flex uses FileRefrence for the user to select the file, then encodes the data and sends it to the server script:

```
<?php
function fileupload($data)
{
    $daily_folder = 'today/';

    $fileName_clipped = substr( $fileName, 0, $max_file_len );
    $fileName_clipped = preg_replace('/\./','_',$fileName_clipped);
    $filePath = '/path/to/storage' . $daily_folder;

    if(!is_dir($filePath))
        mkdir($filePath);

    if( strlen($data->filedata) > 0 ) {
        if( !file_put_contents($filePath . $fileName_clipped, base64_decode($data->filedata)) )
            return false;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Running the process

file A: 31,740B in, 31,848B out, 108B extra

file B: 35,273B in, 31,403B out, 130B extra

I imagine this could be on the Flash side, but honestly it's dirt simple. I just don't see where the extra data is coming in, and why its corrupting the file. Anyone know why this is happening? or better yet, how I can clean these files up now?

Comment: this seems related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1927163/flash-loader-and-bytearray

Comment: Thanks for the link, it does seem similar, perhaps the most important thing I found was I may have been sending the image over from flash pre-corrupted. I used encodedFile.toString(), rather than encodedFile.flush(). So it seems as if I have saved the encoder rather than the file. F!

Comment: Nevermind, the encoder actually uses the flush method in toString(). So that wouldn't have done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the dealio. When I backed up all the images from one server and moved them to another I FTPed all the files onto my Windows laptop. That process, whether because of Windows or perhaps FileZilla, corrupted all of the files. adding a bunch of junk onto them. I'd live input as to what you think caused the problem, but regardless I located the problem and fixed it.

The solution was to zip the parent directory on the server and download the zip. I didn't have to modify any code. Just a simple procedure revision. How lame.

Comment: sounds like text transfer mode was enabled for whatever reason. this will corrupt binary files. more here: http://www.rhinosoft.com/newsletter/NewsL2008-03-18.asp